# Is it possible to make a list of disk in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux

I'm a beginner and not a native english speaker please excuse my clumsiness.

I'm trying to make a linux install script for personal use (and to learn more about linux and bash scripting) but I'm struggling on finding a way to create a disk selection menu :

I wish to make a list witch would look like that :

```
NAME    SIZE    DEVICES
sda     256gib  intel-ssdx
sdb     1000gib TLxxxxxxxx
nvme0n1 128gib  WDxxxxxxxx
```

So far i've tried to echo fdisk -l and lsblk in text file and use cat to prompt it

Code :

```
lsblk
Set DiskLayout=("Automatic Install" "Manual Install" "Check pending change" "Quit")
select DiskLayoutopt in "${DiskLayout[@]}"
do
    case $DiskLayoutopt in
        "Automatic Install")
            read Sdsk -p "Select drive"
            ;;
        "Manual Install")
            parted -a optimal
            ;; 
        "Check pending change")
            echo ""
        "Quit")
            exit 1
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I would first look around where you get the information you need before you start with a menu.

Comment: If you're not constrained to use `bash`, then `lsblk --json` may be your friend. In `bash`, you may be better off just looking at `/sys/class/block/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will get your menu:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

disk=()
size=()
name=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' device; do
    device=${device/\/dev\//}
    disk+=($device)
    name+=("`cat "/sys/class/block/$device/device/model"`")
    size+=("`cat "/sys/class/block/$device/size"`")
done < <(find "/dev/" -regex '/dev/sd[a-z]\|/dev/vd[a-z]\|/dev/hd[a-z]' -print0)

for i in `seq 0 $((${#disk[@]}-1))`; do
    echo -e "${disk[$i]}\t${name[$i]}\t${size[$i]}"
done
```

This is some tough bash script... Hope you'll learn quick. 
Here's some help:

First line is a shebang to tell your system which interpreter is needed for that script. Indeed, this script only works with bash.
Try running with bash myscript.sh on systems that don't work (ie BSD).

`variable=()` is an array.

Adding something to that array is done by `variable+=("my value")`

The while loop reads variable device from what it gets from find command

```
while read device; do
    something
done < <(find)
```

The find command uses a regular expression that says anything like /dev/sdX where X goes from a to z, or anything like /dev/vdX or anything like /dev/hdX (where X still goes from a to z).
The or operator is a pipe `|` which has to be escaped with an antislash, hence giving `\|`.

The devices read by the while look look like '/dev/sda' so we need so strip '/dev/' out of it using the following:

```
device=${device/\/dev\//}
```

This is a bash substitution which works the following way:

```
variable="my foo function"
echo ${variable/foo/bar}
```

This outputs `my bar function`.
Indeed, we still need to escape `/` since this is the separator character for the substition, so it becomes `\/`.

Getting the disk name via

```
"`cat "/sys/class/block/$device/device/model"`"
```

`cat "/sys/class/block/sda/device/model"` gives the disk model.
In order to get the result into a variable, we'll need to quote it with ` sign, eg:

```
myvar=`cat /var/file`
```

Last but not least, the for loop part:

for i in `seq 0 $((${#disk[@]}-1))`; do
       echo -e "${disk[$i]}\t${name[$i]}\t${size[$i]}"
   done

`${#disk[@]}` is the number of elements in array disk.
Actually `${#var}` is the number of elements in var, which when being a string, is the number of characters. `${var[@]}` means all elements of an array.

`seq 0 X` returns a sequence of 0 to X numbers, in order to construct the for loop.

Using `echo -e` translates escaped characters into litterals. In our case '\t' become tabs.
Last but not least, showing `${disk[$i]}` is disk array value of index $i where $i is an integer.

Btw, bash is quite limited to do these tasks, but really fun to learn in the first place.
Harder tasks might be better accomplished in a higher level scripting language like Python. Anyway, have fun learning bash, it's a life saver in sysadmin's career.